# How to allocate a large 3-dimensional array dynamically?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-management

My computer RAM has 32GB of memory available. I want to define a 1500*1500*500 size array. How should I define a dynamic array?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <openacc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

void main(void) {
    #define NX 1501
    #define NY 1501
    #define NZ 501
    int  i, j, k, l, m, dt, nstop;
    double  comp;
    dt = 5;
    nstop = 5
    static double ex[NX][NY][NZ] = { 0. }, ey[NX][NY][NZ] = { 0. }, ez[NX][NY][NZ] = { 0. };
    static double hx[NX][NY][NZ] = { 1. }, hy[NX][NY][NZ] = { 0. }, hz[NX][NY][NZ] = { 1. };
    static double t, comp;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("point A hm=0.csv", "w"); /* Output data file name */

    t = 0.;

    for (l = 0; l < nstop; l++) {
        for (i = 0; i < NX - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < NY - 1; j++) {
                for (k = 1; k < NZ - 1; k++) {
                    ex[i][j][k] =  2 * ey[i][j][k]
                                 + 3 * (hz[i][j][k] - hx[i][j - 1][k])
                                 - 5 * (hy[i][j][k] - 2 * hz[i][j][k - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        comp = ((double)(l + 1) / nstop) * 100.;
        printf("Computation: %4.3f %% completed \r", comp);
        fprintf(file, "%e, %e \n", t * 1e6, -ex[1200][950][20] + ex[1170][950][20]) / 2.);
        t = t + dt;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? You currently have tagged both, but they will have different solutions to this problem.

Comment: That's what [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is for.

Comment: With `sizeof(double) == 8`, each of these arrays is about 8GB large. You are trying to define 6 of them, which results in more memory required than you have.

Comment: FYI, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error in your problem statement:

- the formula to compute `ex[i][j][k]` only depends on values from the other arrays with same `i` index for the first dimension. Since you only output the value of `-ex[1200][950][20] + ex[1170][950][20]) / 2.`, you only need to compute the values for `i=1200` and `i=1170` and there is no need to allocate so much memory.
- furthermore, the computed values in `ex` are the same for all values of `l`. No need to recompute at each iteration.
- finally, given the initialization of the arrays, all values of `ex` for a first index other than 0 are null, so the output is trivial to compute: `0.0`.

More seriously, if the initial values are small integers, the results seem to require only 32-bit integer arithmetics, which would reduce the memory requirements by 50%. Yet this would still exceed the maximum size for statically allocated objects on your system. You should allocate these 3D matrices dynamically this way:

```
    double (*ex)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*ex));
```

Assuming your code is more complex than the sample posted, which incidentally contains a few typos that prevent compilation, here is what the modified code would look like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
#define NX 1501
#define NY 1501
#define NZ 501
    int  i, j, k, l, dt, nstop;
    double comp;
    dt = 5;
    nstop = 5;
    double (*ex)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*ex));
    if (ex == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for ex\n"); exit(1); }
    double (*ey)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*ey));
    if (ey == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for ey\n"); exit(1); }
    double (*ez)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*ez));
    if (ez == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for ez\n"); exit(1); }
    double (*hx)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*hx));
    if (hx == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for hx\n"); exit(1); }
    double (*hy)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*hy));
    if (hy == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for hy\n"); exit(1); }
    double (*hz)[NY][NZ] = calloc(NX, sizeof(*hz));
    if (hz == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed for hz\n"); exit(1); }
    hx[0][0][0] = 1.;
    hz[0][0][0] = 1.;
    // probably many more initializations missing
    double t;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("point A hm=0.csv", "w"); /* Output data file name */
    if (file == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "cannot create output file\n"); exit(1); }

    t = 0.;

    for (l = 0; l < nstop; l++) {
        for (i = 0; i < NX - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < NY - 1; j++) {
                for (k = 1; k < NZ - 1; k++) {
                    ex[i][j][k] =  2 * ey[i][j][k]
                        + 3 * (hz[i][j][k] - hx[i][j - 1][k])
                        - 5 * (hy[i][j][k] - 2 * hz[i][j][k - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        comp = ((double)(l + 1) / nstop) * 100.;
        printf("Computation: %4.3f %% completed \r", comp);
        fprintf(file, "%e, %e \n", t * 1e6, (-ex[1200][950][20] + ex[1170][950][20]) / 2.);
        t = t + dt;
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(ex);
    free(ey);
    free(ez);
    free(hx);
    free(hy);
    free(hz);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C (as your code seems to be), you can for example use a triple pointer and `malloc()`:

```
#define NX 1501
#define NY 1501
#define NZ 501

int*** p_a = malloc(sizeof(double**) * NX);

for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
{
    p_a[i] = malloc(sizeof(double*) * NY)

    for (int j = 0; j < NY; j++)
        p_a[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(double) * NZ);
}
```

A more efficient way would be to use a single pointer and use the size of each dimension in call to `malloc()` at once:

```
double* p_a = malloc(sizeof(*p_a) * (NX * NY * NZ));
```

---

In C++, the most common and efficient way is to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamically allocating an array:

```
#define NX 1501
#define NY 1501
#define NZ 501

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> a(NX, vector<vector<double>>(NY, vector<double>(NZ)));
```

---

Note that the size of a `double` object is on most modern platforms `8` Byte. Means, When you want to achieve what you want, you need at least 8 * 1500 * 1500 * 500 = 9000000000 Byte = about 8,3 Gbyte for each 3D array to allocate it. You define 6 of them, so 49,8 Gbyte are required to **only allocate those arrays** which is not provided by your systems as you said your system has 32 Gbyte available.

Comment: Implementing a three-dimensional array with a pointer to pointers to pointers is inefficient and cumbersome and should not be recommended to students.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What about now? I state both methods as there are possible but explicitly hint the OP to use the second one.

Comment: Why not start with `int arr[500];` declare 1500 of those and 1500 of that?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The OP said s/he wants to use dynamic allocation. But no feedback from her/him if that could be a possible way, too and s/he just misplaced the word "dynamic". However, as far as stated, we´re stuck to dynamic allocation.

Comment: Ah, well, it is all dynamic, it's just using a different type pointer. I dropped an answer as well. I'll have to compare times between using `int ***` and using `int (**)[500]` - both are technically correct, the triple pointer will just be a little more involved in allocating and freeing. (careful with `valgrind` -- I thought I locked my box when it was swapping `:)` -- of course I also had it outputting completion of filling every `1500x500` array)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. If you need to allocate the entire memory structure at once, your probably want to allocate for a *pointer-to-pointer-to-array* `int[500]` (`int (**)[500]`) rather than allocating for a *pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer* `int`  (`int ***`)- though both are technically correct.

(**note:** I used `int` in the example, so just change the type of `a` to `double` to satisfy your needs)

To approach the allocation for a *pointer-to-pointer-to-array* `int[500]`, start with your pointer and allocate `1500` pointers, e.g.

```
#define Z 500
#define X 1500
#define Y X

int main (void) {

    int (**a)[Z] = NULL;            /* pointer to pointer to array of int[500] */

    if (!(a = malloc (X * sizeof *a))) {    /* allocate X pointers to (*)[Z] */
        perror ("malloc-X (**)[Z]");
        return 1;
    }
```

At this point you have 1500 *pointers-to-array-of* `int[500]`. You can loop of each allocated pointer above, allocating `1500 * sizeof (int[500)` and assigning the starting address to each block allocated to one of the pointers, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)                     /* for each pointer */
        if (!(a[i] = malloc (Y * sizeof **a))) {    /* alloc Y * sizeof int[Z] */
            perror ("malloc-YZ (*)[Z]");
            return 1;
        }
```

Now you can address each integer in your allocation as `a[x][y][z]`. Then to free the allocated memory, you just `free()` in the reverse order you allocated, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        free (a[i]);                        /* free allocated blocks */
    free (a);                               /* free pointers */
```

A short example that exercises this and writes a value to each index could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Z 500
#define X 1500
#define Y X

int main (void) {

    int (**a)[Z] = NULL;            /* pointer to pointer to array of int[500] */

    if (!(a = malloc (X * sizeof *a))) {    /* allocate X pointers to (*)[Z] */
        perror ("malloc-X (**)[Z]");
        return 1;
    }
    puts ("pointers allocated");

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)                     /* for each pointer */
        if (!(a[i] = malloc (Y * sizeof **a))) {    /* alloc Y * sizeof int[Z] */
            perror ("malloc-YZ (*)[Z]");
            return 1;
        }
    puts ("all allocated");

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)             /* set mem to prevent optimize out */
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < Z; k++)
                a[i][j][k] = i * j * k;

    puts ("freeing memory");
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
        free (a[i]);                        /* free allocated blocks */
    free (a);                               /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Use/Output -- Timed Run**

```
$ time ./bin/malloc_1500x1500x500
pointers allocated
all allocated
freeing memory

real    0m1.481s
user    0m0.649s
sys     0m0.832s
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

That's 4.5G of memory allocated and used (*warning:* you will swap on 8G or less depending what else you have running if you run `valgrind`)

```
$ valgrind ./bin/malloc_1500x1500x500
==7750== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7750== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7750== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7750== Command: ./bin/malloc_1500x1500x500
==7750==
pointers allocated
all allocated
freeing memory
==7750==
==7750== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7750==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7750==   total heap usage: 1,502 allocs, 1,502 frees, 4,500,013,024 bytes allocated
==7750==
==7750== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7750==
==7750== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7750== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm not sure where I picked up `int` (getting old...) -- that would double the memory usage (ouch) I'll move to a box with more than 8G to test. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.